# Slicing url with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi how to use python to transform the url of a article to it's print url.

article url:http://www.indianexpress.com/news/second-time-as-farce/800228/0

print url:http://www.indianexpress.com/story-print/800228/

How to convert article url to print url?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`urllib.parse.urlparse()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) to carve the path from the rest of the url, and `posixpath.split()` and `posixpath.join()` to reform the path, and [`urllib.parse.urlunparse()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunparse) to put it all back together again.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is posixpath necessary? urlparse is always going to return a forward slash.

Comment: You don't want to use `os.path`, since on Windows that will give you `ntpath` instead.

Comment: Is there something wrong with hard-coding a forward slash in this case?

Comment: Not per se, but there's no need to; "magic numbers" aren't restricted to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def transform(url):
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    return '{0}://{1}/story-print/{2}/'.format(parsed.scheme, parsed.netloc, parsed.path.split('/')[-2])
```

Comment: Always be sure to check the tags.